# Regarding Image Quality in Kurento Remote Stream

Tags: kurento

**What i do:**

1.I installed the kurento Media Server, with reference to the link https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/installation_guide.html

2.Start the Kurento Media Server using the command

```
   sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
```

3.In the client-js ,i used the link https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/kurento-hello-world

4.From the *kurento-hello-world* ,used the commands

```
   bower install
   http-server
```

5.In the browser loaded the page

```
   http://localhost:8080/index.html?ws_uri=ws://localhost:8888/kurento#
```

6.It works well  but the image quality in the remote stream is not as same as the image quality in the local host

7.I have also attached two samples below

[sample-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWIFW.png)
[sample-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Nij.png)

**Note**:

1.I am running in localhost,so it may not be a bandwidth problem.I also tried in AWS server, the same issue occurs.

2.I didin't change the constraints that i pass to the WebRtcPeer in the *client-utils* folder

```
   var MEDIA_CONSTRAINTS = { 
   audio: true, 
   video: { 
   width: 640, 
   framerate: 15 
   } 
   };
```

**What i have to know:**

1.What i have to do to solve this issue?

2.Is there any other way to improve the quality?

**KMS-Version:**

The KMS version which i am using is **6.4.0**.I find it using the log

```
$ kurento-media-server --version
Version: 6.4.0
Found modules:
Module: 'blurtheface' version '0.0.1~0.ga33e8af'
Module: 'core' version '6.4.0'
Module: 'crowddetector' version '6.4.0'
Module: 'detection' version '0.0.1~0.gfa1dc04'
Module: 'elements' version '6.4.0'
Module: 'facedetect' version '0.0.1~0.gfc2892d'
Module: 'filters' version '6.4.0'
Module: 'opencvpluginsample' version '0.0.1~7.g9db5b70'
```

Comment: What's your KMS version?

Comment: I have used KMS 6.

Comment: Which one exactly?

Comment: I am using kurento-media-server-6.0

Comment: You can check the version you are using in your server's log file. The latest release is 6.4.0

Comment: @igracia i have updated my question with the kms version and how i find the version.pls check and reply

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the constraints to send a higher quality video. If you are sending only 640 and 15 fps, you might see that the remote video is of a significantly poorer quality that the one you are getting from your camera.